# Python: UTF16 decoding adds a new blank line on Windows boxes

Tags: python, utf-16

I'm running into an issue with extra newlines on windows versus *nix platforms.

```
file = open('UTF16file.xml', 'rb')
html = file.read().decode('utf-16')
file.close()

regexp = re.compile(self.originalurl, re.S)
(html, changes) = regexp.subn(self.newurl, html)

file = open('UTF16file-regexed.xml', 'w+')
file.write(html.encode('utf-16'))
file.close()
```

Running this code on my mac works - I get my file back without the extra line breaks. So far I've tried:

1. Encoding the regular expression as utf-16 instead of decoding the file - breaks on Windows and OSX.
2. Writing in mode 'wb' instead of 'w+' - breaks on Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Option #2 sounds like the right one. What breaks?

Comment: Are the two files identical (binary?), or is your MacOS text editor fixing double newlines for you?  For #2, have you tried opening the file in Wordpad (or Notepad++, etc) instead of Notepad?  Most text editors more advanced than `notepad.exe` will interpret Linux newlines correctly.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: you shouldn't hide the `file` type with a variable named `file`.

Comment: If you want to learn more about new lines, read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html

Comment: Cristian: Thanks for the link and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Nick>python
ActivePython 2.6.4.10 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jan 22 2010, 16:41:54) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]...
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> txt = """here
... is all
... my text n stuff."""
>>> f = open('u16.txt','wb')
>>> f.write(txt.encode('utf-16'))
>>> f.close()
>>> exit()

C:\Documents and Settings\Nick>notepad u16.txt
```

Looks like:

```
here is allmy text n stuff.
```

(though when I copy-pasted it from Notepad to FF it actually put in line breaks)...but this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Nick>
    "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" u16.txt
```

Looks like:

```
here 
is all
my text n stuff.
```

(on Windows XP SP3 32-bit)